# Eclipse removed a source file from project

Tags: android, eclipse

This is a dumb newbie question, but one that is driving me nuts.

I have an Android project being developed on Eclipse with two source files.  Eclipse for some reason decided I didn't need one of the files and removed it from the project (i.e., I pushed the wrong key at the wrong moment).  Now I only have one source file in my project.  The lost source file is still there in the directory, but Eclipse just doesn't recognize it as part of the project.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dragging the file out of your folder onto the desktop, and then drag it from the desktop into your source folder in eclipse. I've had a handful of different situations where this was necessary.

Comment: Thanks!  You both helped.  I dragged the file from the source directory into Eclipse and then updated with F5.  It is back in the project.

Answer (score 2):

MY first suggestion is press F5 on the source folder.

Second suggestion, right click the project folder->Properties->Java Build Path -> Source - expand ".../src" and ensure your source file is not under the Excluded option.

Comment: Or select File > Refresh from the menu.

Comment: You may also want to try doing Project > Clean, that sometimes helps me solve weird android related issues.